# How to cache some read only xml files in java

Tags: java, xml, multithreading, caching, file-io

I have some xml files that will be read-only that I need to access on a random basis.  They are xml files that contain user data I need to merge with rtf documents.

There will probably be less than 10 files, but more than 5.  As I loop through a list of documents I will have to select the correct xml file for the merge.  I have a cross mapping file that links the document name to the xml file, so I know which one I need as I loop, but I need all of them available as I will be switching constantly between the xml files during the looping process.

Is there a simple solution for this rather than using some open source cache?

Thanks,

James

Comment: Couldn't you just read them into a singleton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.util.Map` is your friend when you don't need a full-grown cache.

Answer (score 3):

If you're reading the XML in as DOM, then you can put the `Document` into your map instead of the file or file name.

**EDIT:** I just realized you said "mapping file", not "map" as in `java.util.Map`. That would be your first step - processing your mapping file and generating that Map of names -> Documents.